# Solução para o file_exists no php check

Tags: php, arquivo

Função alternativa para a função file_exists()

```
define('BASE', 'http://localhost/seusite'); 

public static function checkImageExists($urlImage) {
    $filename = BASE . "/uploads/{$urlImage}";
    $ExtFile = mb_strtolower(strrchr($filename, "."));
    $Extension = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'];
    if (in_array($ExtFile, $Extension) && (@fopen($filename, "r") == true)):
        if (getimagesize($filename)):
            return true;
        else:
            return false;
        endif;
    else:
        return false;
    endif;
}
```

usando a função:

```
checkImageExists(portfolio/2018/02/1-novo-1518485054.jpg);
```

Comment: Já verificou com o [**Xhprof**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.xhprof.php) para ver se isso vale a pena?

Comment: Você está só divulgando a função? Se sim, é melhor utilizar o Github. Com pelo menos 20 de reputação você pode participar do [chat] e divulgá-la lá. Se for alguma dúvida em relação ao código, sua pergunta não foi clara e carece de edição. Faça o [tour] e leia o guia de [ask] para mais detalhes.

Comment: so pra compartilhar mesmo, nao sei mexer aqui ainda!

Comment: Não é necessário FOPEN para usar GETIMAGESIZE, nas verdade o FOPEN vai manter o arquivo aberto até o script finalizar, o que realmente é um baita problema, seria melhor usar só `is_file`

Comment: Caro Romulo, sei que faz tempo, mas gostaria de saber se alguma vez chegou a testar a minha resposta. Até breve.

Answer (score 1):

Não é necessário `fopen` para usar `getimagesize`, nas verdade o `fopen` vai manter o arquivo aberto até o script finalizar, o que realmente é um baita problema, por exemplo se você for fazer operações de deletar ou editar ou mudar o ponteiro de posição.

Outra checagem desnecessária e que pode levar ao erro é a checagem de extensão de arquivo, realmente ela é um tanto quanto desnecessária se for levar em conta que um servidor pode customizar as extensões a ainda sim o conteudo interno do documento for uma imagem.

Seria melhor usar só `is_file` combinado com `getimagesize`, já que o próprio irá apenas reconhecer imagens, assim:

```
function is_image($path)
{
    return is_file($path) && getimagesize($path) !== false;
}
```

O `is_file` checa se é arquivo e se existe, se for pasta ou não existir retorna `false`.

O `getimagesize` retorna sempre array, exceto quando o arquivo não é uma imagem, então no caso `!== false` pode ser um pouco melhor em micro-otimização, por exemplo você vai checar vários arquivos de uma vez uma pasta, aonde poderá conter milhares de arquivos.

Se quiser checar especificos, ao invés de usar `getimagesize` talvez seja mais eficiente usar `finfo`, que usa MAGIC para checar o mime-type do arquivo, por exemplo:

```
class Image
{
    const JPEG = 1;
    const GIF = 2;
    const PNG = 3;
    const WEBP = 4;
    const SVG = 5;

    public static function isImage($path, $type)
    {
        if (is_file($path) === false) {
            return false;
        }

        $mime = self::mime($path);

        switch ($type) {
            case self::JPEG:
                return $mime === 'jpeg';

            case self::GIF:
                return $mime === 'gif';

            case self::PNG:
                return $mime === 'png';

            case self::WEBP:
                return $mime === 'webp';

            case self::SVG:
                return $mime === 'svg+xml';

            default:
                throw new InvalidArgumentException("Argumento precisa ser uma das constantes definidas na class Image");
        }
    }

    private static function mime($path)
    {
        $mime = '';

        if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
            $mime  = finfo_file($finfo, $path);
            finfo_close($finfo);
        } elseif (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
            $mime = mime_content_type($path);
        }

        return strpos($mime, 'image/') === 0 ? substr($mime, 6) : false;
    }
}
```

O uso ficaria bem simples, assim:

```
Image::isImage('image/foto.jpg', Image::JPEG); //Retorna TRUE
Image::isImage('image/foto.jpg', Image::GIF);  //Retorna FALSE
Image::isImage('image/foto.jpg', Image::PNG);  //Retorna FALSE
```

Em um estilo procedural poderia fazer assim:

```
define('IMAGE_JPEG', 1);
define('IMAGE_GIF', 2);
define('IMAGE_PNG', 3);
define('IMAGE_WEBP', 4);
define('IMAGE_SVG', 5);

function is_image($path, $type)
{
    if (is_file($path) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    $mime = image_mime($path);

    switch ($type) {
        case IMAGE_JPEG:
            return $mime === 'jpeg';

        case IMAGE_GIF:
            return $mime === 'gif';

        case IMAGE_PNG:
            return $mime === 'png';

        case IMAGE_WEBP:
            return $mime === 'webp';

        case IMAGE_SVG:
            return $mime === 'svg+xml';

        default:
             throw new InvalidArgumentException("Argumento precisa ser uma das constantes definidas na class Image");
    }
}

function image_mime($path)
{
    $mime = '';

    if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mime  = finfo_file($finfo, $path);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } elseif (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
        $mime = mime_content_type($path);
    }

    return strpos($mime, 'image/') === 0 ? substr($mime, 6) : false;
}
```

O uso seria assim:

```
is_image('image/foto.png', IMAGE_JPEG); //Retorna FALSE
is_image('image/foto.png', IMAGE_GIF);  //Retorna FALSE
is_image('image/foto.png', IMAGE_PNG);  //Retorna TRUE
```